# the output screen is hanging after running this stack implementation in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node {
     string s;
     node* link;
}*top=NULL,*temp,*p;

node* new_node(node a){
     p=new node;
     p->s=a.s;
     p->link=a.link;
     top=p;
}
void showstack(){
     *temp=*top;
     while(temp!=NULL){
          cout<<top->s;
          temp=top->link;
     }
}
int main(){
     char a;
     int m;
     int i=0;
     node push;
     do{  std::cin >> push.s;
          if(top==NULL)
               push.link=NULL;
          else
               push.link=top;
          new_node(push);
          i++;
     }while(i<=5);
     cout<<top->s;
     showstack();
     return 0;
}
```

i wrote the above code trying to implement a linked stack in c++ however after giving the input the program is hanging and no response.why is it so? i checked and rechecked many times and found no bug.pls help!!

Comment: Please apply **C**apitalization rules where appropriate, indent your code and [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48344001/edit) what the question is. Before you do, please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: `temp=top->link;` Here, `top->link` never changes, so `temp` never changes, so loop never ends.

Comment: Run the program in a debugger and when it hangs pause the program and check where it is hanging.

Comment: thanks! but could you please give some links or reference as to where capitalisation must be there? also if possible could u also suggest how i could improve the indentation of the code. @Ron

Comment: ***i checked and rechecked many times and found no bug*** This is why you need to debug your code in an ide with a debugger like Visual Studio. Single step through the code looking at the variables at each step.

Comment: @nwp give a man a bug fix, and he'll eat for a day... give a man a debugger, and he can catch his own bugs?

Comment: Don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Ever.

Comment: does it have any other disadvantage other than its compilation time?? @ChristianHackl

Comment: @VarunKrishna you might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: @VarunKrishna: All disadvantages which "Lightness Races in Orbit" lists in the excellent answer to the question linked by UKMonkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
*temp = *top;
```

with

```
temp = top;
```

Think about where `temp` points and draw boxes and arrows on some paper to understand why.

(And don't use global variables when local variables will do. It's just asking for trouble.)